# Getting JSON data from server running on localhost

Tags: java, testing, rest-assured, java-http-client

I'm trying to do some API testing but I'm not sure how to get started. Like in Java, how could I read in the response of a server for example:

```
localhost:3000/ping
```

the response is:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "alive": true
    }
}
```

Looks like httpclient is no longer being developed, so I looked into REST-Assured (https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/). My question is, how could I translate this to javacode? I was looking at httpclient, but I don't even know how to use it. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks much!

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Example_1_-_JSON 
Seams pretty straight forward. What is it you are confused about?

Comment: Yea, I've read that, but like at the top of example 1, where it says *"Assume that the GET request (to http://localhost:8080/lotto) returns JSON..."* how can I connect to localhost to read the json data into Java so I can manipulate it

Comment: The library IS in java. If you want to change the port, see https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Default_values

Comment: Would you like to share this library? I don't really know what you mean. I'm new to all this

Comment: Take a look at Retrofit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import com.jayway.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

public class TestRest {
    public void doTest() {
        String json = given().port(3000).get("/ping").toString();
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

To import library into maven:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

### Edit

To do this without static references:

```
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;

public class testAPI {
    public void doTest() {
        String json = RestAssured.given().port(3000).get("/ping").toString();
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand now! I do have one issue, the org.hamcrest.Matchers.*; doesn't seem to exist, where could I find this jar or it's mvn coordinates, .Matchers doesn't seem to exist anymore?

Comment: @mosawi Updated answer with maven dependency

Comment: You are awesome!! Thank you!! I appreciate your responses. the keyword given() still doesn't seem to work? I've updated my question to show what I'm talking about

Comment: @mosawi Have you tried typing it and compiling it in spite of eclipses errors? Eclipse doesn’t always do well on static imports.

Comment: Yes I have, I know this is a petty question but it's preventing it from working. It may have to do with another issue I'm having. I will try to solve that and will report back if it works. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @mosawi I added a section for using it without static references. See if that helps.